# Can every functor $F: \bf{Vect} \to \bf{Top}$ be lifted to a functor $\tilde F: \bf{VectBun} \to \bf{Bun}$? And if $F: \bf{Vect} \to \bf{Man}$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles

My question is: if I have a functor from the category of vector spaces **Vect** to the category of topological spaces **Top** (or differentiable manifolds **Man**) can I lift it to a functor from the category of vector bundles **VectBun** to the category of topological (or differentiable) bundles **Bun**?

Let $F:$ **Vect** $\to$ **Top** be a functor. I want to define $\tilde F:$ **VectBun** $\to$ **Bun**.

1. Objects. If $\pi: E \to B$ is a vector bundle, I can define $\tilde F(E) = \bigcup_{p\in B} F(E_p)$ and the obvious projection $\tilde \pi: \tilde F(E) \to B$. If $(U_i, \phi_i)_i$ is an atlas for $E$ I can define  $\tilde \phi_i: \tilde \pi^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i \times F(\mathbb{R}^r)$ such that $\tilde \phi_i(\tilde e) = F(\phi_i|_{\{p\} \times E_p})(\tilde e)$ where $p = \tilde \pi(\tilde e)$. I can set a topology on $\tilde E$ saying that $A \subseteq \tilde E$ is open if and only if $\tilde \phi_i(A \cap \tilde\pi^{-1}(U_i))$ is open for every $i$.
2. Arrows. ...

My question are:

1. Is it correct? To me, that seems correct, but I am afraid because functors "are not continuous in $p$" (I hope that it's clear what I am trying to say)
2. Does this work also in the smooth category? If $F:$ **Vect** $\to$ **Man** , then $\tilde F(E)$ is a manifold? Again, my doubts come from the fact that functor are not "smooth in $p$"

In fact, for 2, I have that $(\tilde \phi_j  \tilde \phi_i ^{-1})(p, x) = F(\phi_j  \tilde \phi_i ^{-1}|_{\{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^r})(p, x)$ and $p$ is *inside* the functor. Then I don't know if $\tilde \phi_j  \tilde \phi_i ^{-1}$.

Comment: I think this can be understood better in terms of classifying spaces.  Basically $F$ induces a map of the nerve of the category of isomorphismes of vector spaces to that of the homeomorphisms of spaces, so that it induces a functor between the classifying spaces of the nerves of these categories.  As these classifying spaces classify vector bundles and bundles over spaces, from this you get your $\tilde{F}$.  What is scary for me here is that usually we work with the group completion of these monoids, so we would $F$ to be monoidal, but somehow in your case, we don't seem to need this...

Comment: Your categories are topologically enriched and you need your functor to be continuous. Then your construction will provide continuous cocycles i.e bundles.

Comment: @ThorbenK To me seems that the "just topological" construction works, even if my functors are not continuous. Am I wrong?

Comment: For your transition functions to be continuous (smooth) you need your functor to be continuous (smooth)

Comment: @ThorbenK The topology I set on $\tilde E$ makes $\tilde \phi_i$ continuos, isn't it?

Comment: No. It all boils down to you not writing anything about morphisms. Why is $\tilde{\Phi}$ open for example? If you would write it down more carefully and really checking all the axioms you would see that it fails.

Comment: @ThorbenK You are right about morphisms: there is no way to prove that they are continuous. But I still believe that the objects are well-defined, i.e. are topological spaces. The functions $\tilde \phi_i$ are open because if we take $A \subseteq \tilde \pi^{-1}(U_i)$, then, by definition, $\tilde\phi_i(A)$ is open.

Comment: Perhaps it's helpful to break it by restricting to a single object: at the end of the day, you have a homomorphism $GL_n \to Homeo(F)$ for some $n$ and some $F$, and you need this to be continuous. (At a high level, we are simply taking "B" of this map, but of course it's helpful to write down what's really happening at the level of transition functioms etc.)